Can't update or change anything related with kernel
I have Ubuntu 22.04 and just replaced my GPU (AMD Radeon 5700 -> AMD Radeon 6900).
Now it boots into a black screen when the UI is supposed to load. But that's not why I'm writing here for now. (I think I can solve this anyhow.) My problem is something different: I can no longer change anything in the kernel:
No matter what I do, I get the messages like "package could not be found". Other programs can be installed normally via apt.
Here are a few examples:
ben@Ben-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'linux-generic' has no installation candidate
ben@Ben-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic' has no installation candidate

Yesterday I already tried half a day, and in doing so I quietly threw down the (still executable) 5.15 kernel that was still on it. So now I only have 6.2.0-26, which at least allows me to enter safe mode.
My repositories look ok, for me:
ben@Ben-PC:~$ grep ^[^#] /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main universe restricted multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/amdgpu-proprietary.list:deb https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.2/ubuntu jammy proprietary
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/amdgpu-proprietary.list.save:deb https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.2/ubuntu jammy proprietary
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/amdgpu.list:deb https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.2/ubuntu jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/amdgpu.list.dpkg-old:deb https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.2/ubuntu jammy main #Orginal https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.1.1/ubuntu
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/amdgpu.list.save:deb https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.2/ubuntu jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/brostrend.list:deb https://linux.brostrend.com stable main previous
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/brostrend.list.save:deb https://linux.brostrend.com stable main previous
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cappelikan-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/cappelikan/ppa/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/damentz-ubuntu-liquorix-jammy.list:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/damentz/liquorix/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/damentz-ubuntu-liquorix-jammy.list.save:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/damentz/liquorix/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/danielrichter2007-ubuntu-grub-customizer-jammy.list:deb
https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/danielrichter2007-ubuntu-grub-customizer-jammy.list.save:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu/
jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ernstp-ubuntu-mesarc-jammy.list:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ernstp/mesarc/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ernstp-ubuntu-mesarc-jammy.list.save:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ernstp/mesarc/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list.save:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/rocm.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/6.2 jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/rocm.list.dpkg-old:deb https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/6.2 jammy main #Original https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/6.1.1
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/rocm.list.save:deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/6.2 jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/teamviewer-keyring.gpg] https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/teamviewer-keyring.gpg] https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb preview main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list.dpkg-old:deb http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list.save:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/teamviewer-keyring.gpg] https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list.save:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/teamviewer-keyring.gpg] https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb preview main

Is it possible, that my 6.2 header is lost?
 dpkg -l | grep linux-headers
ii  linux-headers-6.8.12-060812                6.8.12-060812.202405300722
                 all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 6.8.12
iU  linux-headers-6.8.12-060812-generic        6.8.12-060812.202405300722
                 amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 6.8.12 on 64 bit
x86 SMP

What can I do to fix this problem?
Update:
Even Mainline Leeds to errors:
$ sudo mainline install-latest
mainline 1.4.10
Updating Kernels...
Wird Heruntergeladen 6.11
Installiert 6.11
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket linux-modules-6.11.0-061100-generic wird gewählt.
(Lese Datenbank ... 203197 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../linux-modules-6.11.0-061100-generic_6.11.0-061100.202409151536_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von linux-modules-6.11.0-061100-generic (6.11.0-061100.202409151536) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket linux-headers-6.11.0-061100-generic wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../linux-headers-6.11.0-061100-generic_6.11.0-061100.202409151536_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von linux-headers-6.11.0-061100-generic (6.11.0-061100.202409151536) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket linux-headers-6.11.0-061100 wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../linux-headers-6.11.0-061100_6.11.0-061100.202409151536_all.deb ...
Entpacken von linux-headers-6.11.0-061100 (6.11.0-061100.202409151536) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket linux-image-unsigned-6.11.0-061100-generic wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../linux-image-unsigned-6.11.0-061100-generic_6.11.0-061100.202409151536_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von linux-image-unsigned-6.11.0-061100-generic (6.11.0-061100.202409151536) ...
linux-modules-6.11.0-061100-generic (6.11.0-061100.202409151536) wird eingerichtet ...
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von linux-headers-6.11.0-061100-generic:
 linux-headers-6.11.0-061100-generic hängt ab von libc6 (>= 2.38); aber:
  Version von libc6:amd64 auf dem System ist 2.35-0ubuntu3.8.
 linux-headers-6.11.0-061100-generic hängt ab von libelf1t64 (>= 0.144); aber:
  Paket libelf1t64 ist nicht installiert.
 linux-headers-6.11.0-061100-generic hängt ab von libssl3t64 (>= 3.0.0); aber:
  Paket libssl3t64 ist nicht installiert.
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes linux-headers-6.11.0-061100-generic (--install):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
linux-headers-6.11.0-061100 (6.11.0-061100.202409151536) wird eingerichtet ...
linux-image-unsigned-6.11.0-061100-generic (6.11.0-061100.202409151536) wird eingerichtet ...
I: /boot/vmlinuz is now a symlink to vmlinuz-6.11.0-061100-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img is now a symlink to initrd.img-6.11.0-061100-generic
Trigger für linux-image-unsigned-6.11.0-061100-generic (6.11.0-061100.202409151536) werden verarbeitet ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.11.0-061100-generic
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File: /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/source/dkms.conf does not exist.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 4
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes linux-image-unsigned-6.11.0-061100-generic (--install):
 »installiertes linux-image-unsigned-6.11.0-061100-generic-Skript des Paketes post-installation«-Unterprozess gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurück
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 linux-headers-6.11.0-061100-generic
 linux-image-unsigned-6.11.0-061100-generic
mainline: fertige

Update2:
I remove the 6900 and brout the 5700 back in Place. Now Gnome is starting normal again. But i still cant install any kernel:
udo apt install linux-generic
Paketlisten werden gelesen… Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut… Fertig
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen… Fertig
Paket linux-generic ist nicht verfügbar, wird aber von einem anderen Paket
referenziert. Das kann heißen, dass das Paket fehlt, dass es abgelöst
wurde oder nur aus einer anderen Quelle verfügbar ist.

E: Für Paket »linux-generic« existiert kein Installationskandidat.


https://xyproblem.info/ ? What is it that you think you need 6.2 for?

I am not fixed on 6.2!
I'm happy with any version that can install an AMD driver for the 6900 and my wifi adapter (wich has never been problematic yet).
I get the simlar errors no matter which kernel I try to install:
sudo apt-get install linux-image-5.15.0-25-generic
[...]
Paket linux-image-5.15.0-25-generic ist nicht verfügbar, wird aber von einem anderen Paket
referenziert. Das kann heißen, dass das Paket fehlt, dass es abgelöst
wurde oder nur aus einer anderen Quelle verfügbar ist.
E: Für Paket »linux-image-5.15.0-25-generic« existiert kein Installationskandidat.

You don't seem to have jammy-updates anywhere in that incredible sources list. Have you never done any updates?

Right. Well observed. Thank you.
I just don't know why. The checkmarks in the UI are set. I'll do some research.
